# CSS Animation: TranslateZ cannot be applied to text inside a div

Tags: css, css-animations

I am trying to apply `transform:translateZ(50px)` to the `h`, `p` tags which should appear like it's floating since I'm using `transform-style: preserve-3d`. When I inspect the `h`, and `p` tags, it appears to be floating but not the text. Refer this pen [here](https://codepen.io/lavisor/pen/WNvzqNo) for more clarity.

HTML:

```
<div class="card" id="moveContainer">
<div class="card-content">
  <h1>Center Text </h1>
  <p>Sample papagraph</p>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
 body {
  background: #000;
  -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
  perspective: 1000px;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}

.card {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
  background: #efaefa;
  opacity: 0.3;
  display: flex;
  border-radius: 4px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.button-primary {
  min-width: 150px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  min-width: 150px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  background: #ba00da;
  display: inline;
}

.button-primary span {
  transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 50px);
}

.card-content {
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.card-content h1 {    
  transform: translateZ(50px);
}

.card-content p {
  transform: translateZ(50px);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I am seeing that on card class, you are using opacity:0.3. That opacity is creating issue. you can read more about that from below links**

[enter link description here](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2016Jun/0026.html)

[enter link description here](https://css-tricks.com/things-watch-working-css-3d/)

```js
var mouse_monitor = function(e) {
    var x = e.pageX;
    var y = e.pageY;

    var aX = ((window.innerWidth/2) - x) / 30;
    var aY = ((window.innerHeight/2) - y) / 10;

    transform(-aX, aY , document.getElementById('moveContainer'));
  }

  function transform(aX , aY, ele){
    ele.style = "transform: rotateX("+ aY+"deg) rotateY("+aX+"deg)";
  }

  window.onload = function() {
    this.addEventListener('mousemove', mouse_monitor);
  }
```

```css
body {
  background: #000;
  -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
  perspective: 1000px;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}

.card {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
  background: #47344b;
  display: flex;
  border-radius: 4px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.button-primary {
  min-width: 150px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  min-width: 150px;
  padding: 5px 10px;

  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  background: #ba00da;
  display: inline;
}

.button-primary span {
  transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 50px);
}
.card-content {
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  color: white;
}

.card-content h1 {
  transform:translateZ(100px);
}

.card-content p {
  transform:translateZ(50px);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="card" id="moveContainer">
<div class="card-content">
  <h1>Center Text </h1>
  <p>Sample papagraph</p>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I was looking for something like this effect here: https://codepen.io/ariona/pen/JopOOr , Even though I used the same styles i'm not getting the floating effectI was looking for. I'm not able to find out what i'm missing.

Comment: @KishoreL I have updated my answer. You can check it now. Opacity is creating issue in your code. If it make sense to you, Please accept the answer.